# Filling input fields with a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

After looking for about an hour, I can't find anyone who has shared their way of filling input fields on an HTML page from a JSON array with corresponding values.

For example, the name of the input box is the first element of the array, then the value that should go inside is the second.

More example:

input form is as follows...

```
<input type="text" id="123111" data-inline="true" class="firstclass" name="xx3111" data-theme="b" style="color: red;">
```

and the JSON array is:

```
000001: "firstValue"
000002: "secondValue"
000003: "thirdValue"
000004: "fourthValue"
etc, etc
```

What I want to do is fill the corresponding input box with the value in the array. Another example:

input with id 000123 is filled with the string in the array that has the number 000123

`<input type="text" id="000001">` is filled with the string firstValue

Comment: Have you written any javascript?

Comment: That isn't a JSON array.

Comment: This is not an array but javascript object. And if it's an object then it's not a JSON too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through every property of the data object and select corresponding input element, then set its value:

```
for (var key in data) {
    document.getElementById(key).value = data[key];
}
```

The `data` is the object you called "JSON array".

Comment: This is the pure solution, opposed to mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(json, function(index, value) {
    $('input#' + index).val(value);
});
```

B/c I'm lazy I just used jQuery. The concept is the same weather you're using pure js, or another library like underscore. I'm assuming your JSON array is valid and you've just displayed it incorrectly.

Comment: I was voted down because? You don't like jQuery? That's not a valid reason.

Comment: I did not downvote but the question is not tagged with JQuery.

Comment: No worries, I guess someone just didn't like the question, not your answer (or mine) ;) The answer is correct.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans So? It's still js. This isn't a "write my code for me" forum. I displayed the concept to solve his issue, even writing that it can be adapted to whatever he's using, if he uses a different library.

Comment: Like I said, I did not downvote and I like JQuery too. However if a question is not tagged with JQuery and it is with Javascript then a pure Javascript solution/answer is recommended/desired. What's the point of tagging if you don't take this in account.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select DOM elements (in this case input field) by `id` and if you are not 100% sure that the id exists you need to check for `null` or `undefined`.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/cjax5kb2/3/)

```
var mydata ={
    "000001": "firstValue",
    "000002": "secondValue",
    "000003": "thirdValue",
    "000000": "This id does not exist",
    "000004": "fourthValue"
}


for (var k in mydata) {
      var input = document.getElementById(k);
      if(typeof input !== 'undefined' && input !== null) {//skip non exixting ids
        input.value= mydata[k];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make one input field, based on value and id
function makeField(value, id) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = id;
    input.className = 'firstclass';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.setAttribute('data-inline', "true");
    input.setAttribute('data-inline', "true");
    input.setAttribute('data-theme', "b");
    input.setAttribute('style', "color:red;");
    input.setAttribute('value', value);
    return input;
}

// Make many fields, from an object.
function makeInputsFromObject(obj) {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        id,
        input;
    for (id in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, id)) {
            fragment.appendChild(makeField(obj[id], id));
        }
    }
    return fragment;
}

// Make many fields, from an array.
function makeInputsFromArray(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(
        function (fragment, value, id) {
            fragment.appendChild(makeField(value, id));
            return fragment;
        },
        document.createDocumentFragment()
    );
}

// Test/demonstration code below.

document.body.appendChild(
    makeInputsFromObject({
        "000001": "firstValue",
        "000002": "secondValue",
        "000003": "thirdValue",
        "000004": "fourthValue"
    })
);

document.body.appendChild(
    makeInputsFromArray([
        "fifthValue",
        "sixthValue",
        "seventhValue",
        "eighthValue"
    ])
);
```

As the test/demo code shows, you feed your data structure to one of the makeInputs functions (whichever is appropriate), and the function will return a DOM node (actually a DocumentFragment). Add that to the DOM in the usual way, and it'll give you your fields.

As the Array version highlights, you can implement this as a reduce() operation if you're actually working with an Array. Objects don't have a built-in reduce()-like function, so we improvise on that, but the general principle is the same, and we can even use the same makeField() function.

Be warned: neither version customizes things to quite the degree you're looking for. The Array version doesn't quite do IDs right, and neither version exactly matches your scheme for the name attribute. But I hope this illustrates the principle.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for filling input fields on an HTML page from a JSON array with corresponding values.

1. First get the output values in your javascript function.
2. Then loop through the json array with $.each function like below.
3. Then loop again through the input fields in your HTML function.
4. If the array key in your json array matches the id, put the json value there as input value.

---

I have tried to illustrate it roughly in the following way:

```
<?php
            $.ajax({
                url : path/to/json/output/file,
                type : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
                dataType : 'json',

                error: function(){
                        $('#result_table_json').append('<p>Error Loading Data</p>');
                        },

                success :function(response){
                //get the array element one by one in the following loop
                    $.each(row,function(key,value){
                        //now check for the right input id that matches the key. I guess all your inputs have something in common eg. class name. So loop through the fields
                        $.each(".firstclass")function(){

                            if( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) === key )
                            {   //fill the input field here 
                                $(this).val(value);                                         }
                            //Alternatively you may append the fields externally in case they dont exist without the json values like this:
                            //$('#result_table_json').append('<input type="text" id="'+key+'" data-inline="true" class="firstclass" name="'+key+'" data-theme="b" value="'+value+'" style="color: red;">');
                        });     
                    });


                }

            });
    ?>
```